# Help clearing up the definition of Limsup?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

I was thinking about the equivalence of the two following definition of Limsup of a sequence.
I find the definition 1 much more intuitive and I have been trying to convince myself of the equivalence of the two definitions given below but I haven't succeeded yet

Def 1 Let $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers and we define $S$ as the set of all subsequential limits of the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$.
Then we define $\limsup x_n=\sup S$
Now this makes sense as if the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ does not converge we can think about the supremum( and infimum) of its sub-sequential limits

Def 2: $\limsup x_n=\inf_{k}\{\sup {x_n}\}$ where the supremum over $n \geq k$

In this definition I see why it is defined the way it is, as we need the supremum of those $x_n$ as $n \to \infty$ so we take the infimum over the set of supremums (of a sets with fewer element  as n increases we eventually are talking about the supremums of those $x_n$ with inifinitely high values of n . 
But I am not at all convinced that these two definitions are equivalent. Can someone help me see wy they are equivalent.This has troubled me and makes me uncomfortable everytime I have to deal with Limsups and Liminfs.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just prove this carefully.
Let $A = \inf_N \sup _{n>N} x_n, B =  \sup S$.

1. Let $r>0$. You can find a convergent subsequence $x'$ such as
   $$
   x'_n \to L > B - r
   $$
   Now let $N>0$. $\sup _{n>N} x_n \ge L$ because infinitely many terms of $x'$ are in the set $\{x_n : n>  N \}$. Hence $$A \ge L >  B-r
   $$and as this is true for every $r>0$: $$A\ge B$$
2. Let $r>0$. There is a $N$ such as
   $$\sup _{n>N} x_n < A + r
   $$
   Then for every convergent subsequence $x'$, as infinitely many terms are in $\{x_n : n>  N \}$:
   $$
   \lim x' < A+r
   $$and as it is true for every $x'$:
   $$
   B \le A + r
   $$and as it is true for every $r>0$:
   $$
   B \le A
   $$

Comment: Merci beaucoup.I am now convinced and I am very grateful for you time and assitance

Comment: pas de probleme ;)